# list(rrule.between(start,last,inc=True)) is not including the start date

Tags: python, date, datetime, rrule, meeting-request

```
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20231214T170000Z;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=TH;WKST=SU
```

Converted the RRULE to string using

```
.decode(utf-8)
rrule=rrulestr(rrule_str)
```

The list of dates doesn't include the start date when I use

```
list(rrule.between(start,last,inc=True))
```

but includes the last.
Sometimes it does include the start but then it excludes the last.

This is an example:
start=2023-06-28 15:04:16+00:00
last=2023-12-14 15:04:16+00:00
mlist=list(rrule.between(start.astimezone(pytz.utc),last.astimezone(pytz.utc),inc=True))

Output list doesn't contain start at times and contains the last. Sometimes it contains the start and doesn't output the last although it should be giving both as per the documentation.

Comment: The events occur at a specific time of day. What time of day is in `start` and `last`? If it's after 17:00, the start date won't be included.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)